# Ember: how do you access the model from the router?

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

Based on what I've read (please correct me if I'm mistaken), the logic that handles when a model should be saved and where to transition next should be in the router.

If that is the case, I'm running into a bit of a problem: **I don't know how to access the model from the route**.

This is my controller (and the console logs "CREATED" after I press submit):

```
App.ScoutsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  submit: ->
    model = @get('model')
    model.on 'didCreate', ->
      console.log 'CREATED' # I want to  redirect to the index after creation
    model.save()
```

I should move that logic into the route, right? Let's try that:

```
App.ScoutsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.Scout.createRecord()

  events:
    submit: ->
      # Based on what I've read, the right place to put the code you see in the controller is here. How do I get access to the model?
      # I have tried @get('model'), @get('content')
```

Note: I understand that the submit event bubbles up from the view, to the controller, then finally the route, stopping at any one of them that has "submit" defined. So since I want the route to handle it, I removed the controller. I'm able to see any `console.log` done in the route, I just need to be able to get to the model instance.

I'm using `Ember v1.0.0-rc.5-7-g610589a`

Thanks!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Two options: `this.currentModel` or `this.modelFor(routeName)`

#### Update

I spoke to Señor Alex Matchneer about this. There are no plans for `this.currentModel` to go away anytime soon, but he considers `this.modelFor(this.routeName)` the public API.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I will end up getting currentModel. How did you know about that? Can't seem to find it in the docs.

Comment: I've worked in that part of the codebase a bunch. Will you consider opening a PR to add it to the docs? It's not hard to do, and I can coach you if you need help.

Comment: Sure. Cloning the website now!

Comment: Should I really use `this.currentModel` though? The lack of documentation plus the fact that it is only set in a private method https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L555 makes me think it's not meant for me to use. Always use this.modelFor(routeName) instead?

Comment: `this.currentModel` is perfect, but I too would like to see an authoritative documentation source on it.

Comment: I spoke to Señor Alex Matchneer about this. No plans for `this.currentModel` to go away anytime soon, but he considers `this.modelFor(this.routeName)` the public API.

Answer (score 2):

what should work is

```
this.controllerFor('ScoutsNew').get('content')
```

Comment: oh, then i am sorry. Can you give me a link where this stands.

Comment: In the official API, where it should be? If not there... http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html

Comment: sorry, but i don't get it. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_controllerFor isn't marked as deprecated.

Comment: content is deprecated, but model is correct: `this.controllerFor('ScoutsNew').get('model')`

Comment: @MichaelJohnston `content` is not deprecated. Also `model` is an alias to `content`. See the API for ObjectController (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ObjectController.html#property_content) and for ArrayController(http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_content)

Answer (score 2):

`this.currentModel` isn't really the approved way as described [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11760)

but in my version of Ember (1.11) `this.modelFor(this.routeName)` returns null, so this is what worked for me

```
this.controllerFor(this.routeName).get('model')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `this.controller.get('model');` but there are plans to remove the controller.

Till that we can use the above code to retrieve the routes current model

Answer (score 0):

With Ember 3.0.0 this is a documented way that works for me:

```
const model = this.controller.model;
```